# AJAX-PHP: Returns wrong response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm currently working on an PHP- Function, that's called via AJAX. It turns Base64- Strings into images. The Problem is, that the ajax call echoes the base64- String to the Front- End, instead of just my other output.

The image gets created on the Server, no Problem at all. But on the site, where you start this action (via an ajax- call) returns not only the

```
"done <br />"
```

but also the whole base64- String of the image.

The AJAX Call looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#lii-form').submit(function() {

        data = {
            action: 'lii_map_images'
        };

        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){
            $('#lii_log').html(response);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The PHP- Function looks like this: (Everything works, except for the base64- string- output [which shouldn't output])

```
$imgUrl = $aduser -> getFoto();
$imgUrl = substr( $imgUrl, 0, -3 );
error_log($imgUrl); // tried it without this line, still prints

// turn String to image
$data = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $base64_string);
$data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);

$img_data = imagecreatefromstring($data);
$file = $uploaddir."/".$filename;

imagejpeg($img_data, $file);
imagedestroy($img_data);

echo "done <br />";
```

I'm working with Wordpress, btw.

**EDIT**

The output looks like this:

[image: wtf]

**EDIT 2**

I tried to remove the response from the ajax call:

```
   $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){
        $('#lii_log').html(response);
    });
```

to

```
   $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){

    });
```

but it still showed the image data.

**EDIT 3**

The Image- data seems to be more of a raw jpeg data than base64.

Comment: You save the image on your server right? If so, instead of echoing `done <br />`, echo the files location `echo $file;`

Comment: @LinkinTED well I could do that, but that isn't the problem. I know where the file is. It's there, not corrupt and everything ok. Just on the front-end it echoes the base64- value of it and "done", instead of just "done"

Comment: quick fix `ob_start();...ob_end_clean()`

Comment: @cske tried it, still get the other output.... :(

Comment: is that same as before after using @cske recommendation, what have you done, can you share with us

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi yeah, it's the same output. I added ob_start(); at the top of the functiont, and ob_end_clean(); at the end of it..

Comment: Could you show the method from `$aduser->getFoto()`?

Comment: @Repox it's not a real method, it just returns a string (the base64string)

Comment: @Zanidd, how? From a model? Or?

Comment: @Repox It's a method that gets the image of an active directory user. It's from our enterprise framwork and gets used on multiple websites (mostly by me) It works and is tested. It's tottally not causing the problem.

Comment: @Zanidd, I just don't get it. It seems like `$imgUrl` is used for anything, so what does the code do?

Comment: Can you double check that your `$file` variable is correct and writable when you call `imagejpeg`? Do you see any errors/warnings in the log?

Comment: Everything is fine with that function. I checked it right now. No errors in the server log